# Vuetify Datatable Select All Not Working With Regular v-checkbox

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, vuetify-datatable

I am currently trying to customize the select all checkbox for a [Vue Datatable](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables/) (`v-datatable`). All I'd really like to do is add a label or perhaps a tooltip to the checkbox itself. To do this, I'd like to utilize the [Header Data Table Select Slot](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-data-table/#slots-header.data-table-select)/`header.data-table-select`, and change the element from a `v-simple-checkbox` to a regular `v-checkbox`.

When I add in a template that uses the `v-simple-checkbox`, the checkbox works perfectly fine. You can click it and select/deselect all of the rows without an issue. [Here is a Codepen showcasing this](https://codepen.io/FrankFromWork1/pen/Yzrxaym).

However, if I use the regular `v-checkbox`, then the select/deselect all functionality leaves entirely. [This Codepen showcases this](https://codepen.io/FrankFromWork1/pen/JjryLPe).

What do I have to hook the `on` value up to in order to get it to work correctly in this case since `v-on` does not seem to doing it? Or is there an easier way to customize this checkbox that I'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setup your `v-checkbox` like this

```html
<v-checkbox
   :input-value="props.value"
   :indeterminate="props.indeterminate"
   @change="on.input"
>
</v-checkbox>
```